# Plasma Desktop: Can I move Atom's Main menu to Panel like on Unity

Tags: unity, kubuntu, gui, plasma, atom

Atom editor's Main menu does not match my desktop design and changing Atom's UI does not change the main menu color. I need that menu so I can't just hide it. Can I move it on panel like on Unity?

(I use Kubuntu)

Screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can move it to the panel thanks to plasma 5.9.x app menu; unfortunately, there's a bug with electron (atom base) abusing the plasma app menu to 100% CPU: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8455
I've got a feeling both Kubuntu 17.04 and this electron issue will get solved at the same time...Can't wait! :-)